# What advantage FC function component has over vanilla React function component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have seen this `FC` function component:

```js
const LabelForm: FC<LabelFormProps> = ({
  labels,
  selectedID,
}) => {
  const selectedLabel = selectedID !== undefined && labels[selectedID];
```

usually I implement like this:

```js
interface EventProps {
  lang: string;
  translations: Translation;
  eventId: string;
}

function Event(props: EventProps) {
  const { lang, translations, eventId } = props;
```

Is it only a syntax sugar, or has any advantage over vanilla one?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not an advantage these days! CRA has actually walked this standard back, hence why it doesn't ship by default anymore in a default  `npx create-react-app --typescript`.

Here's an GitHub issue that talks about it!

Essentially it implicitly implies that there will always be children by default, which is not necessary and could potentially lead to bugs!

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177